# Unifying list of lists prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I googled this but cant find the answer, so here you go:

I have this function in prolog:

```
ing(Lis) :- findall(I,( recipe2(_,ingredients(I,_)) ),Lis).
```

This function search and returns me a list of lists like this:

```
L = [['wheat flour', egg, salt], ['wheat flour', cheese, olives, tomato, salt, basil], ['wheat flour', potatoes, salt], [milk, egg, sugar]].
```

I want to unify that list of lists in only one list, so i can get out duplicates. I know i have to use recursion, but thats all i know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply modify the predicate like such:

```
ing(Lis) :-
    setof(E, X^Y^I^( recipe2(X, ingredients(I,Y)), member(E, I) ), Lis).
```

`member/2` is a built-in predicate that unifies the first argument with an element of a list in the second argument. It is non-deterministic.

The use of `X^Y^I^` are existential quantifiers to ensure that you only get your results in one solution. It essentially says,

> There exists an X, Y, and I for any element E that is a part of an
>   ingredient list, (I).

Using `setof/3` also ensures that any solution you get will be a collection of unique elements.

---

Documentation (SWI-Prolog) for [member/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2) and [setof/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setof/3)

Comment: right, but since OP's needs is removing duplicates, better use setof/3, or sort/2 after findall/3

Comment: @CapelliC, thanks for pointing that out. The part of the question that referred to handling duplicates completely escaped my mind for some odd reason. I've edited my answer.